# Google interview problem description Gas station

Tags: algorithm

I am not able to understand the below problem description asked in google many times

**Problem Description**

On a horizontal number line, we have gas stations at positions `stations[0]`, `stations[1]`, ..., `stations[N-1]`, where `N = stations.length`.

Now, we add `K` more gas stations so that `D`, the maximum distance between adjacent gas stations, is minimized.

Return the smallest possible value of D.

Example:

Input: stations = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], K = 9

Output: 0.500000

**My doubt**

suppose if `arr = {1,5,10}`
and`k=2` then we can fit both gas stations between 1 and 5 at any distance then the max distance between adjacent gas 10 and 5 will be maximized
stations will be `10-5=5` (according to me it is the answer)

But the answer is `2.5` it seems that optimal approach will be one between 1 and 5 `at dist=2 from both 1 and 5` other between 
5 and 10 `at dist=2.5 from both`

Comment: Could you tell us what you don't understand ? From the last paragraph it seam that you understood the problem, or is it part of the problem statement ?

Comment: I Edited the problem

Comment: You say you think the goal is to **maximize** the distance, but it is to **minimize** it.

Comment: I don't understand your doubt. The goal is to minimize the max distance between adjacent stations. By inserting a station between each given station you divide the interval by two. (5-1)/2 = 2 and (10-5)/2=2.5. The max distance is 2.5 which is the answer.

Comment: The goal of the problem is to minimise the distance between two adjacent pumps such that no other two pumps have greater distance than that.

Comment: Do we assume gas stations don't take up any horizontal space whatsoever? :)

Answer (score 1):

In this example it's obvious that dist = 2.5 cause of the dist between 5 and 10. Now, let's think about the solution to this problem. If we will have a dist = x we can simply check if we can solve it with this distance by greedy placing element after dist *x*. So we will do it in O(n). But how we can get the best score? It's simple binary search with min = 0 and max = maxDistBetweenTwoElements. And if we will get some value we will check it in linear time so complexity will be O(n logn). You should also consider some precision. For example, score will be +/- 0.000001 - it should be OK but you have to remember about this during your interview.

Comment: This assumes there is a smallest distance between two elements. But if we allow fractions, like 2.5, we can keep dividing a positive number by two.

Comment: No, it's not because of this part ```You should also consider some precision. For example, score will be +/- 0.000001``` It is a very common idea in competitive programming for example in this task. https://codeforces.com/contest/782/problem/B

Comment: The precision you describe should be part of the problem constraints but it seems to be missing.

Comment: After some googling I found some comments about this problem and some of Google SE commented that it may be solved as binary search or as a dynamic programming, but both solutions are correct.

Comment: So what is the precision for this problem?